# Unable to install dual boot ubuntu on windows 10; caps lock key keeps blinking

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10, capslock

I am trying to install dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 onto Win10 w/USB stick, but after selecting anything from the purple menu (Try w/o installing, install, etc.), the screen flashes, goes black and then nothing happens except the caps lock key starts blinking.  I've used this same USB ISO to install Ubuntu several other times.  I've tried both USB ports.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I'm running Win 10 x64, v. 1709, build 16299.371; on HP Envy x360 15m-bq0xx, AMD-FX-9800P, Radeon R7 2.7GHz, 8gb RAM.

Comment: Does Windows still boot ok? Have you read this page: https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c01732674#AbT2

Comment: @Noki Yep, I'm in Windows now on the same laptop.  Nothing unusual happens in Windows.  The article you linked doesn't apply.  tyvm

Comment: Very odd, have you tried making the USB stick again? Or another version of Ubuntu/Linux? Annoying I know but sounds like you need to start narrowing things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With kudos going to @Noki, I fixed this issue by downloading and re-creating the ISO on the same USB drive.  There doesn't seem to have been a problem with the stick itself, just a glitch, even though I'd used that same ISO several times.  With the fresh version, I encountered no problems.